# Need a do-it-yourself replacement for tab groups in Firefox 57

Tags: firefox, html, browser-tabs, firefox-57

The recent update to `Firefox 57` marked my favourite `Tab Groups` extension obsolete; the `Firefox Multi-Account Containers` extension it offers is nowhere near adequate - this apparent beta can't even move tabs between groups. (On the positive side, the new rendering engine fixes performance issues added two releases ago.) I'm trying to rig up a temporary solution in a hope they will do something about this one too eventually.

What I currently settled on is the `Tree Style Tab` extension combined with a set of silly local pages of the following form used as group roots:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Group Name</title>
<body></body>
</html>
```

However, I can't find a way to protect them from accidental closing. Tried pinning them, but a pinned tab cannot have children. Even worse, a closed parent tab also closes its children with no way to restore them all at once. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The workaround I chose is to use [Firefox ESR](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) (Extended Support Release).
This release is based on Firefox 52 and will be supported until June 26 2018. Hopefully then a useable replacement for `Tab Groups` will have emerged and stabilized.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm aware of `Firefox ESR`. The issue with it is that the now-obsolete versions of add-ons it runs, including `Adblock`, `NoScript` and other essential ones, are not likely to get timely updates, nor are website, antivirus, etc. developers going to take the obsolete versions of both browser and add-ons into account. The whole thing is going to become unfit for everyday use long before June - that was exactly the reason I dropped my beloved old `Opera`.